# How can I increase text size on TM-U220B Dot Metrics receipt printer using esc_pos_printer flutter library?

Tags: flutter, printing, epson, receipt

Has anyone worked with [esc_pos_printer](https://pub.dev/packages/esc_pos_printer) flutter package for printing receipt with epson printer, I have two printers.
TM-T88VI : Thermal Printer
TM-U220B : Dot Metrics
 `printer.text('Item Name', styles: PosStyles( height: PosTextSize.size2, width: PosTextSize.size2, ));`
PosTextSize option not working for TM-U220B : Dot Metrics printer

[Current Print Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eYR7.png)

I am expecting bigger text on Dot Metrics printer as well but same code not supported by dot metrics printer.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi @bqubique, have you used esc_pos_printer lib in your project?

Comment: I fond the solution, have to add HEX commands manually with text.